# javascript focus a webcontrol

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-controls

Javscript is not my main language but I believe it is the only solution to my problem.  If I am in a webcontrol and the user clicks on a button it saves the data.  What I want it to also do is to redirect them to another webcontrol on that same page.  Example.  The first webcontrol gets general knowledge from the user about their preferred Model of car.  If they Select Ford, Chevy, Dodge, etc. It then redirects them to the respective Ford tab, Chevy tab, Dodge tab.  All of the webcontrols sit inside a webform and are in a tabcontainer.

Comment: You'll need to get the Id of the element that you are trying to set focus to.  Once you have that you can execute the following script: `document.getElementById('id').focus();` (assuming that the Id of the element is 'id').

Comment: Have you tried actual .Focus method (e.g. `MyWebControl.Focus()`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I have registered the pages in the front end and it calls their source but the only methods that it allows are .equals or .ReferenceEquals in the code behind